# Clear Memcached on CakePHP 3.4

Tags: caching, memcached, cakephp-3.4

I'm using memcached engine on CakePHP 3.4.

I would like to use a simple command in PHP, empty all content stored in memcached.

I followed the documentation, it works very well by emptying an item.

Exemple : `Cache::delete('products', 'mymemconfig');` works fine.

Now, how can i do tu remove all cache keys stored in *mymemconfig* ?

I tried `Cache::clear(false, 'mymemconfig');`, that does'n work...

Would you have a solution?

Comment: Anybody can help ?

Comment: Could you show how you have configured `mymemconfig`. Do you have `'prefix'` in your `Cache::config`?